# What condition is needed for a matrix $A(t)$ to commute with its derivative?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $A(t): (0, \tau)\subset\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow P^{+}_n$, where by $P^{+}_n$ we mean the set of positive-definite matrices of dimension $n$.
Now the question is which conditions assures us that 
$$\dot{A}(t)A(t)=A(t)\dot{A}(t).$$

Comment: You may be intersted in this: https://www.google.com/search?q=Matrices+that+commute+with+their+derivative.&oq=Matrices+that+commute+with+their+derivative.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l3.498j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8